How can we use probabilities non-pragmatically within our finitude?
There is usually the notion the we don't require certainty for knowledge. This usually comes through an assessment of probabilities. This is entailed in induction(which are probabilistic), including inference to the best explanation(the most likely explanation).
But to me this would entail a closed-off, certain base. To say, for example, 1/2 or 1/50, entails the 2 or the 50 to be fixed and certain. Even ranges where it is not fixed but certain and known requires this sort of "containment" of the variables. But how can that be justified? All of this, including the framing seems wildly subjective.
Let's say that every day during 10 years the mailman comes around the corner. We can make an inference that the likelihood that the mailman doesn't come this day is 1/3650 or something of that sort. But this assumes the framing is closed, that the proper, objective "measurement" for inference is the days. Maybe, the mailman didn't come because he got sick, so beyond the 1/3650, we would need to include the likelihood of him having a "can't go to work" sick day. Maybe he was battling terminal cancer, and so the likelihood of him dying would have been far greater than the 1/3,650.
This assumes that our everyday understanding of reality and hence our framing of its local conditions for our analysis can be used to determine things. In short, it bakes in a determination upon which the analysis is built. But how can that determination, which ought to be objective, be determined as such objectively and contained? What if frogs start raining, atoms decompose, what if an unknown cosmic anomaly destroys our planet or our Universe? Our model of reality is contained within as a subset within the limits of our imagination, and the possibilities of reality could far outstrip our imagination, including the possibilities within reality that destroy our determination?

Indeed there're various kinds of uncertainty in reality and we usually use credible interval or confidence interval to quantify uncertainty after we infer some point estimate of your concerned probabilistic model's parameter, or if you stay with the posterior distribution then there're still many statistical metrics applied to empirically validated representative tests such as divergence, distance, error rate, MSE, etc to quantify such gap corresponding to reality...

@DoubleKnot
Thank you for the response, but I guess I am still not understanding how can we justify the confidence in such tools. If we take them as created tools, they would be contingent upon our access to reality as such and for reality as such to be in such a way to correspond confidently with those tools. But how can we justify that?

Indeed the root philosophical confusion is you think you're only using some secondary tools to try to carve out nature at its joint with some certain and unavoidable error and uncertainty, not unlike the famous humble Godel sentence which says 'I can never be proved water tight' corresponding to the ultimate unadulterated reality as its own model. Popper once set out to try to seek and define what he calls similitude to try to quantitatively measure this similarity to reality (or equivalently the uncertainty) without success. Some other philosophers outright reject corresponding theory...

@DoubleKnot Sure, because it seems we have both, right? Certainty and uncertainty. We cannot have mere uncertainty and it's clear we don't have absolute and certainty either.
I don't think the correspondence theory(if I am understanding you well) can even in principle be rejected. It's a primitive notion, like that of reality or truth. Even similitude implies correspondence(even if not identical correspondence, at least, essential or formal correspondence; that is, analogical correspondence).
This seems to be quite a non-trivial issue that must be resolved for even basic epistemology

Indeed Carnap believed it's also a deeply non-trivial central epistemic issue and spent his remaining life searching for his famous degree of confirmation theory without success either. Yet it seems a simple conclusion in the same way that we cannot have good without bad. If someone is purely good but they still know bad. So your wish is like to only use the formal good to measure how similar it really is to the formal bad and end up with infinite regressive traps of cycles. Kant called this kind of situation as true universal antimony. That's why there're also conherentism and infinitism...

I think this is still effectively a claim and how are we to judge it epistemically? Coherentism requires(and in fact, assumes) a foundationalism. infinitism, I haven't research much into because seems obviously empty and if grounded would need... well a ground. You can't avoid the ground, or the foundation. Any negation of this would be assuming its own truth and hence its own correspondence through the linguistic with the Real and hence a foundation in the Real, which needs to be justified in order to be called knowledge. I don't see any principled way out of this, seems a base requirement

You're on the right track philosophically speaking and begins to Really feel like the famous Münchhausen trilemma, maybe in this case there's absolutely no uncertainty for you regarding the Real state of affairs of the human knowledge if it has a Real state of affairs?...

@DoubleKnot That is precisely the crux of the issue. To even claim uncertainty is grounded in a performative certainty. I do think we have certainty. "Certain" certainty even if not absolute certainty of some things. Things like our subjectivity, logic, appearances, and so on. From these meaningful categories arise(like reality, ethics, external/internal) which seem meaningful within these previous foundational structures. Even their questioning assumes them, internally at least. But this does seem to assume a non-hostile, benevolent Absolute so that this self-ground is not destroyed

On idealist terms, it is the transcendental categories that pull the phenomenal/immanent ego from its own illegitimate solipsism, and open it unto stable grounds. But are these transcendental branch-categories are themselves grounded? I think the unavoidable answer is yes, the question then becomes HOW are they grounded? And to do that we need to posit a relation between the Absolute(the ground) and the ego, which cannot be sourced in the ego itself. The ego can speak of itself as its own self-ground but not as its own self-ground in the Absolute. Does that make sense?

Of course without making sense of this central issue involving the extremely elusive Kantian antimony of phenomena and noumena, how can you compose such a long thread and stay on it for several days at least?...

@DoubleKnot
I work at home on the computer and have no life :D


What if frogs start raining

It is not about imagination, of course in some sense everything is possible: it is about trusting the uniformity/regularity/rationality of Cosmos as a whole, and that it is not just playing tricks on us.  And the point, put simply, is: such a trust, aka an inductive attitude, is the only attitude that actually makes sense... (for us, see the last paragraph.)
Indeed, induction (as in inductive reasoning, not as in mathematical induction) is not probabilistic reasoning, which itself is just yet another mode of deduction.  As for a "justification of induction", the last two chapters of P.F. Strawson, Introduction to Logical Theory, are exactly about what "inductive reasoning" actually is, how asking for a "justification" is in fact senseless, and even how all other modes of reasoning are actually founded on induction.
Also, relevant for a properly philosophical but also sociological perspective: D.C. Williams, The Evils of Inductive Skepticism.

That said, for an even broader context, I shall mention that a "problem of induction" is especially pertinent to western philosophy (and culture and society) and the specific form in our culture taken by the primality of reason as a tool for understanding.  Via Socrates we inherit from eastern traditions the way (to liberation and wisdom) of the mind, as opposed to the way of the heart or the way of the body (see e.g. the three forms of Yoga).  Later Socrates is "rejected", in practice we progressively lose the holistic and (immanently) spiritual connections, which is the beginning of an era of "separation", where "(the problem of) induction" is the modern name for the specific "problem/mode" of a specific way of understanding and action, the western way essentially, at the stage at which it happens to be.  --  In my understanding: anyway hoping this gives some more coordinates.


it is about trusting the uniformity/regularity/rationality of Cosmos as a whole

But what justifies this trust? As it stands, this seems like an existentialist approach of faith(postulating the existential requirement of hope, or a correspondence between Absolute or reality as such and the individual despite the human finitude).
Will look for the Strawson book. As per williams article, I found it really interesting, thank you, but I think it fails

The reason why I think it fails(at resolving my doubts) is that, as I understand it(and correct me if I'm wrong), beyond the rhetoric(which I don't object to), is a question begging assertion that the loss of induction leads to absurdity. Of course, this is already an inducted reasoning and so question begs. But beyond this question begging, hides maybe the issue that the autonomous process of reason is self-undermining. Williams does not seem to provide the ground other than say a lack of ground is untenable. Which I can agree with but doesn't resolve the issue as to the nature of it.

In some sense, it reminds me of the notion that undermining ethics leads to a loss of the political and similar arguing from the consequences. Which, of course does not address the issue of grounding ethics or how to ground ethics or what does this condition tells us of ethics(or induction). But there's another pressing issue: even if we were to grant induction in the general, we still need to justify EACH specific induction as justified and we cannot do so by appealing to a general justification. Yet this problem also remains unsolved as far as I can tell

It is not unsolved, it is indeed a false problem and you are talking cheap nonsense. But of course, if we have a right, beside that of polluting and appropriating, it's the right to talk nonsense...  Indeed, good luck with that, you too, and EOD.
